# How to disable messages in unix if mesg and chgrp not allowed?

Tags: permissions, terminal, tty, group

This is one of my questions for my exam ..

We are not supposed to use `mesg y/n` for this but we should effectively avoid mesgs along with the problem of not being able to change groups.

Comment: Constraints seem a bit contrived.  Perhaps `chmod g= "$(tty)"`?

Comment: Ummm, its allowed on your exam to have Unix & Linux Stack Exchange answer the question for you?

Comment: Yes but my exam is over long back :P

Answer (score 1):

`mesg` just changes the permissions on your tty, so `mesg y` does

```
chmod 620 `tty`
```

and `mesg n` does

```
chmod 600 `tty`
```

i.e. enabling and disabling group write access to the tty device.